# Periodically look at a pipe and extract new output that has been produced since the last time I have looked at it

Tags: shell-script, pipe

I am reading a continuously growing output of a pipe (for example output from `inotifywait`).

I need to periodically examine the pipe output and extract all new output that has been produced since the last time I have looked at it.

How do I do this in a shell script? I'm out ideas of keywords to use for googling.

Comment: A FIFO buffer may be better to use than a pipe - what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am looking at inotifywait output, exactly like in the example. I mentioned `pipe` as I imagine next I should pipe that output to something to process it. The output comes in bursts: few lines now, another chunk of lines several hours later and so on. Instead staring at it in the terminal, I want to have the output periodically examined to determine what's new since last examination and do something with these new lines (save to a timestamp-pattern file, email it etc), the key question being how do I identify these new lines using a shell script or any other linux utilities

Comment: [Could this post help you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash) You can try to have your output be concatenated to a file and then have some function read the file use the output as new input for another command.

Answer (score 4):

The data in a pipe can only be read once; the "what's new" part is easy.  Just create a named pipe with `mkfifo`, redirect your inotifywait output to it with `>` and read the pipe periodically.

The trickier part is reading a pipe, which is open for write somewhere, without blocking.  dd can do this.

Here's the setup I used to create and continuously write to a pipe:

```
mkfifo foo
( while true ; do date; sleep 1 ; done ) > foo
```

And to read all unread data:

```
dd iflag=nonblock if=foo bs=1M count=1 of=buffer.txt
```

You can change `of=...` to an output file of your choosing.

Sooner or later you will get a partial line from the pipe, so make sure your script can handle this.  For the kind of activity you describe, a good approach is to repeat the dd in append mode until the buffer is newline-terminated:

```
buf=buffer.txt
pipe=foo
> $buf # empty the buffer
until [[ $( tail -c1 $buf | od -a ) == *nl* ]] # nl means newline
do
  dd iflag=nonblock oflag=append conv=notrunc if=$pipe bs=1M count=1 of=$buf
  ls -l $buf # see how it grows
  sleep 1 # if the writer dies, this loop will be infinite and we don't want to kill the CPU
done
do_stuff.sh < $buf
# rm $buf
```

EDIT: it appears you want to tell inotifywait when you're at the terminal and dump everything that's new.  That's easier.  Make a file like whatsnew.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "waiting for first output ... "
while true
do
    n=0
    while read -t0.1 line
    do
        echo "[$line]"
        (( n++ ))
    done
    read -p "$n new lines.  Press any key to try again... " -n1 -s </dev/tty
    echo
done
```

Then start it up:

```
inotifywait | whatsnew.sh
```

Comment: _the "what's new" part is easy_ <- do you think you can explain that as well? I believe inotifywait will print only LF terminated lines; my primary interest of the question is in the "what's new" detection logic / script. I might have misstated the question, thinking I can only do this with reading the output as a pipe (inotifywait | whatsnew.sh). reading from a file to which I'd be redirecting the inotifywait output would do that as well (whatsnew.sh /path/to/output)

Comment: It's easy because reading the output consumes it.   What has been read cannot be read again.  Whatever you do read will be new.  My answer describes reading a named pipe, not a regular file.  Reading from a pipeline is the same except the piped-to process never exits.     It doesn't matter that it prints only complete lines; the printing takes non-zero time and sooner or later your read and inotifywait's write will occur simultaneously.  If you perform blocking waits (i.e. normal reads), the I/O will be buffered and you will not get partial lines.  See my edits.

Comment: Thank you, we are on the right track, but again I must have been misunderstood for the following: insted of effectively looking at the output I really meant the script to "look" at the output, not the human to look, so I can further send that processed output over email. Apologies, english is not my native language. So instead of manually responding to read call, I am looking to periodically (let's say once a minute) have the script examine the pipe. Also, I am observing you are reading with a timeout of 0.1 seconds. What if the pipe is delivering data at a much bigger rate, can lines be lost?

Comment: If you want to check every minute, replace the `read -p ...` prompt with `sleep 60`.  The `while .. done` loop is one check, and it can be piped to a program like mail, e.g.  `while ... done | Mail -s output me@example.com` or redirected to a file `while ... done > output.txt`.  The capacity of a pipe is probably 64KB on your system.   If it overflows, the writer will block (wait) on write.  If you're worried about that, send inotifywait output to a file, and use `tail -f inotifywait_output.txt | whatsnew.sh` to do the periodic checking.

Comment: I replaced the `read` line with `sleep 60`, but now I am getting a blank new line as output from `whatsnew.sh`. I did not expect that, how do I get a new line only with effective new output from the pipe, and not blank new lines for each `sleep`? I definitely do not want to get a blank notification for each cycle check. Also still waiting for the answer to the question related to the 0.1 timeout and potential lost lines in between two cycle runs. Thank you!

Comment: The blank line comes from `echo` after read/sleep.  I answered the question about lost lines already in my previous comment.  Data is not lost but a full pipe will cause the writer to wait for the pipe to empty (i.e., get read)  You can buffer to a file and follow it with tail -f, as described in my previous comment, to avoid this kind of waiting.  I believe it's time to award the bounty.